# How to pop up sliding panel when tap a button on a bottom navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile-application

gif1: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldqHqicHFEauUQbz1fzH5K8XRS3ICNqL/view?usp=sharing
gif2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NpPVrO9trMbde-rPmbAGeHRVSh28BfPk/view?usp=sharing

i'm making an app that using map and bottomnavigation bar and sliding-up panel.
what my problem is that like in the first gif I want to make bottom navigation bar and sliding up panel(or draggable scrollable sheet). when I drag the whole panel down it disappear and when I tap the icon on the navigation bar, it appears again

but in the second gif which I made does not
it does not disappear even if dragging the whole panel down. well I can adjust the minimum height of the panel to make the panel disappear but there's no way to pop up the panel when I tap the button again

I used this package https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel
I think there is not an option that i want in this package(could be wrong! please notify me if I'm wrong)
so my question is that is there a flutter package that can implement the function that I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, and see if it helpful to you

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final double _sheetSize = 0.4;
  _onItemTapped(index) {
    setState(() {
      DraggableScrollableActuator.reset(context);
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          initialChildSize: _sheetSize,
          minChildSize: 0.0,
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]